# How to inject adapter with hilt in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

If Adapter have an interface like clickListener, Fragment implement that interface and Fragment pass the instance of interface in constructor to the adapter, How to inject adapter with hilt?

How to solve this issue?

*Here is the error*

**error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ... cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment: Fragment(), ShowsAdapter.Interaction {

@Inject
lateinit var adapter: ShowsAdapter
private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.my_nav)
....
}


class ShowsAdapter @Inject constructor(private val interaction: Interaction) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowsAdapter.ShowsHolder>() {
....
    interface Interaction {
        fun onItemSelected(show: Show)
    }
}


@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
abstract class HomeModule {

@Binds
abstract fun provideInteraction(homeFragment: HomeFragment): ShowsAdapter.Interaction

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: You should provide the listener not via constructor, but via a setter method instead. That way Hilt can provide you the Adapter and then you will set the listener on it in your Fragment.